# GroupStyleSelector for a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, collections, groupstyle

I am trying to make a custom groupstyle sector for my ListView as per other questions I've seen here on stack overflow.

```
public class TestGroupStyleSelector : GroupStyleSelector
{
    protected override GroupStyle SelectGroupStyleCore(object item, uint level)
    {
            return (GroupStyle)App.Current.Resources["grpStyle"];
    }
}

<ListView GroupStyleSelector="{StaticResource grpStyleSelector}">
```

I have two errors with this:

Error   1   'TestGroupStyleSelector': cannot derive from sealed type 'System.Windows.Controls.GroupStyleSelector'

Error   2   An object of the type "TestGroupStyleSelector" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Controls.GroupStyleSelector".

I have declared the class as other questions on here have shown, I am pretty lost at this point as to how to create a groupstyleselector for my listview, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In WPF, using

```
<ListView GroupStyleSelector="{StaticResource grpStyleSelector}" />
```

and inheriting your selector from **GroupStyleSelector** will result in a 'cannot derive from sealed type 'System.Windows.Controls.GroupStyleSelector' exception.

Instead, use

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.GroupStyle>
     <GroupStyle ContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource grpStyleSelector}"  />
   </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

and inherit your selector from **StyleSelector**

Answer (score 2):

`GroupStyleSelector` is a `Delegate` exposed by `ItemsControl`:

Usage:

```
public GroupStyleSelector GroupStyleSelector
{
    get => (GroupStyleSelector)GetValue(GroupStyleSelectorProperty);
    set => SetValue(GroupStyleSelectorProperty, value);
}
```

Declaration:

```
public delegate GroupStyle GroupStyleSelector(CollectionViewGroup group, int level);
```

It is of type `delegate` which can't be inherited from as per the language specifications.

What you need to do is create a class deriving from `StyleSelector`:

```
public class GroupStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {   
        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```